# Function argument treated as undeclared

Tags: c

I've prepared this simple example which is not working for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fp;
char filename[] = "damy.txt";

void echo (char[] text)
{
    fp = fopen(filename, "a");
    fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf(text);
}

int main ()
{
    echo("foo bar");
    return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to write both to command window and to file. However, this gives compilation error - the `text` used in echo() is not declared. Does c need another declaration of the variable?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: Prefer `printf("%s", text);` to `printf(text);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `char text[]` or `char* text`, not `char[] text`.

Comment: in the parameter list to the function

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
void echo (char [] text )
```

should be:

```
void echo (char text [])
```

And you need:

```
#include <string.h>
```

to get the declaration of the `strlen` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're supposed to do "char *" not "char []"

Comment: A string is not an array of char!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the syntax

`char[] var;`

is a javaism. In C it should be `char var[]`. Moreover you must add `#include <string.h>`